# Why does SAP JCo raise an error "Field ... not a member of ..." even though the field exists?

Tags: java, saprfc, jco

I want to send data to SAP RFC table from my Servlet Application.

I am trying to do this below way.

```
JCO.Function function = null;
Connection conn = new Connection();
JCO.Client mConnection = conn.open();
JCO.Repository mRepository;
mConnection.connect();

mRepository = new JCO.Repository("KEYWORD",mConnection);

try{
    function = this.createFunction("MY RFC NAME");
    if(function != null){
         function.getImportParameterList.setValue("ID1","USERID");
         function.getImportParameterList.setValue("Test Name","UNAME");
         function.getImportParameterList.setValue("CLASSA","UCLASS");

         mConnection.execute(function);
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
    // Exception handling goes here.
}
conn.disconnected();
```

But I am getting following error

> com.sap.mw.jco.JCO$Exception:<127> JCO_ERROR_FIELD_NOT_FOUND: Field USERID not a member of INPUT

But I checked, There is exist column in SAP.

What is missing here?
Should I pass RFC table name also? Then How?

Comment: `function.getImportParameterList.setValue` is a strong indicator that what you posted is not the actual code, as is the fact that `MY TABLE FIELD` does not appear anywhere in your code. If you leave out the important bits, it's unlikely you'll get a helpful answer.

Comment: Please see updated answer. replaced `My TABLE FIELD` with `USERID`.

Comment: Again - I doubt that this is the actual code, it should be `getImportParameterList().setValue`. What is MY RFC NAME, what is its signature?

Comment: My RFC NAME is name of `FUNCTION MODULE`.

Comment: Yes. What is THE ACTUAL NAME of the function module? What is its signature? Please post some more information if you want an actual answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this question by following code.

```
JCO.Function function = null;
Connection conn = new Connection();
JCO.Client mConnection = conn.open();
JCO.Table GET_DATA = null;
JCO.Repository mRepository;
mConnection.connect();

mRepository = new JCO.Repository("KEYWORD",mConnection);

try{
    function = this.createFunction("MY RFC NAME");
    if(function != null){

         GET_DATA = function.getTableParameterList.getTable(TABLE_NAME);
         GET_DATA.appendRow();

         function.getImportParameterList.setValue("ID1","USERID");
         function.getImportParameterList.setValue("Test Name","UNAME");
         function.getImportParameterList.setValue("CLASSA","UCLASS");

         GET_DATA.nextRow();
         mConnection.execute(function);
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
    // Exception handling goes here.
}
conn.disconnected();
```

Answer (score 1):

does this function exist on the sap system connected? 
If so I would suggest to use `function = conn.getRepository.getFunction('MY_RFC_NAME')` instead. With that method you get the meta data and signature of the function modul as it exist on the connected SAP system. This allows you to check if the function exist `if(function == null) throw new Exception("Function Module MY_RFC_NAME does not exist on connected SAP Syste");` and also to check each parameter if he exist and does have the name and type you expect.

In most cases that kind of error occures because a parameter is named slightly different. For example `USER_ID` instead of `USERID`.

Comment: Please see my answer below. I already solved my problem using below code. Please check it.